# WM6.5 Read recived email with pocket outlook

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm out of ideas. Tried many solution for hours without solving.

Problem:
Programmatically read received emails and download attachments.

Okey, so got configured outlook mail on device.

Tried with Pocket Outlook dll and nothing.

Going to jump over the windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tried with Pocket Outlook dll and nothing" is not at all helpful.  What did you try?  What, exactly, was the result?  Reading emails is done with the Pocket Outlook Object Model (POOM).  You don't even say what language you're trying to use, but here are some places to start.

For Managed code use the [`EmailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.emailmessage.aspx) class in the [`Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.aspx) namespace.

For native code, it's a little less intuitive that you have to use [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415647.aspx), but it's still well documented.  [Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raffael/archive/2008/09/08/mapi-on-windows-mobile-6-programmatically-retrieve-mail-body-sample-code.aspx) of getting an email body.

Comment: Im not going to jump over the window now. Thank you